# input type not aligning in resposive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input

My twitter bootstrap input type text is different in firefox and chrome

[firefox](http://s18.postimg.org/k2zhawd3d/firefox1.jpg)

[chrome](http://s23.postimg.org/xhgdazlff/chrome.png)

Comment: Create a fiddle with your html + css.

Comment: ok thanks for your comment Its already done